# Como puedo volver a un punto anterior en python?

Tags: python

Tengo un menú simple, y luego esto:

```
if opcion=="1":
  os.system('cls')
  print('Ocultando...')

elif opcion=="2":
  os.system('cls')
  print('Mostrando...')
else:
  os.system('cls')
  print('{}Opcion invalida'.format(RED))
```

Como puedo hacer para que cuando llegue al else vuelva al menu?

Comment: Recuerdo mucho cuando me hice esa pregunta al empezar a programar ;) Lo que debes hacer es usar un ciclo `while`, y puedes colocar que dentro de las opciones `"1"` y `"2"`, haya un `break`, que rompa el ciclo.

Comment: Encierra todo en un `while True:`

Comment: Toma, te será de gran apoyo: https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/pythonya/

Comment: También, para casos más complejos puedes hacer una función que se llame a si misma.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo mas simple en este caso seria ponerlo en un While True, de manera que cuando llegue al else vuelva al menú.
Esto quedaría implementado de la siguiente manera:

```
while True:
    print("MENU\n"
          "Elija entre las siguientes opciones:\n"
          "1: ...\n"
          "2: ...\n"
          "3: cerrar sistema" #Salir del while para no volver al menú
          )
    opcion=input()

    if opcion== "1":
        os.system('cls')
        print('Ocultando...')
        # Vuelve al menú, pero si quieres que el proceso acabe aquí y no vuelva al menú coloca un "break"
     
    elif opcion== "2":
        os.system('cls')
        print('Mostrando...')
        # Vuelve al menú, pero si quieres que el proceso acabe aquí y no vuelva al menú coloca un "break"

    elif opcion == "3":
        break
        #Se cierra el sistema

    else:
        os.system('cls')
        print("\033[;31m"+"Opción inválida"+'\033[0;m')  #Esta línea sera imprimida en color rojo
        # Luego vuelve al menú
```

Espero que pueda servirte de ayuda.